# Nodejs 5 won't support serialport2 npm...any alternatives to serialport ?

Tags: node.js, serial-port

I am unable to install serialport npm on latest nodejs version,however it works fine with nodejs v0.12...but is there any alternative to this module which can run on nodejs 5.11..or is there any fix so that i can continue using it on nodejs5.11

Comment: What happens when you try to install it? Which OS are you running?

Comment: `serialport2` is 4 years old, use [`serialport`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport).

Comment: yeah tried serialport also....same problem repeats

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Can you please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936310/serialport-module-in-node-js-works-only-if-minicom-is-active-on-the-port) issue? Would appreciate any pointers...